# How to print the best matching hit in the BLAST search? / BioPython

Tags: biopython, blast, hit

I'm trying to making a BLAST search with a nucleotide sequence and print the best matching hit but not sure about which option/command should I use. There are options like `max_hpsp` and `best_hit_overhang`. I don't have an idea about their differences and I want to print just 1 hit. (best matching one) Should i use `max_hpsp 1`?

I wrote this code but it's still not useful. If you could tell me, where I am mistaken and what should to do, I would be very appreciated :) Thank you!

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
seq = Seq("GTTGA......CT")
def best_matching_hit(seq):
    try:
        result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seq)
    except:
        print('BLAST run failed!')
        return None
    blast_record = NCBIXML.read(result_handle)
    for hit in blast_record.alignments:
        for hsp in hit.hsps:
            if hsp.expect == max_hsps 1:
                print(hit.title)
                print(hsp.sbjct)

    
best_matching_hit(seq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this returns just one hit , the first one I suppose, as per

[Limiting the number of hits in a Biopython NCBIWWW Search](https://www.biostars.org/p/373821/) on Biostars:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun  7 15:28:11 2021

@author: Pietro


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67872118/how-to-print-the-best-matching-hit-in-the-blast-search-biopython

"""


from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

from Bio.Seq import Seq

seq = Seq("ATGGCGTGGAATGAGCCTGGAAATAACAACGGCAACAATGGCCGCGATAATGACCCTTGGGGTAATAA\
          TAATCGTGGTGGCCAGCGTCCTGGTGGCCGAGATCAAGGTCCGCCAGATTTAGATGAAGTGTTCAACAA\
          ACTGAGTCAAAAGCTGGGTGGCAAGTTTGGTAAAAAAGGCGGCGGTGGTTCCTCTATCGGCGGTGGCGG\
          TGGTGCAATTGGCTTTGGTGTCATTGCGATCATTGCAATTGCGGTGTGGATTTTCGCTGGTTTTTACAC\
          CATCGGTGAAGCAGAGCGTGGTGTTGTACTGCGTTTAGGTAAATACGATCGTATCGTAGACCCAGGCCT\
          TAACTGGCGTCCTCGTTTTATTGATGAATACGAAGCGGTTAACGTACAAGCGATTCGCTCACTACGTGC\
          ATCTGGTCTAATGCTGACGAAAGATGAAAACGTAGTAACGGTTGCAATGGACGTTCAATACCGAGTTGC\
          TGACCCATACAAATACCTATACCGCGTGACCAATGCAGATGATAGCTTGCGTCAAGCAACAGACTCTGC\
          GCTACGTGCGGTAATTGGTGATTCACTAATGGATAGCATTCTAACCAGTGGTCGTCAGCAAATTCGTCA\
          AAGCACTCAAGAAACACTAAACCAAATCATCGATAGCTATGATATGGGTCTGGTGATTGTTGACGTGAA\
          CTTCCAGTCTGCACGTCCGCCAGAGCAAGTAAAAGATGCGTTTGATGACGCGATTGCTGCGCGTGAGGA\
          TGAAGAGCGTTTCATCCGTGAAGCAGAAGCTTACAAGAACGAAATCTTGCCGAAGGCAACGGGTCGTGC\
          TGAACGTTTGAAGAAGGAAGCTCAAGGTTACAACGAGCGTGTAACTAACGAAGCATTAGGTCAAGTAGC\
          ACAGTTTGAAAAACTACTACCTGAATACCAAGCGGCTCCTGGCGTAACACGTGACCGTCTGTACATTGA\
          CGCGATGGAAGAGGTTTACACCAACACATCTAAAGTGTTGATTGACTCTGAATCAAGCGGCAACCTTTT\
          GTACCTACCAATCGATAAATTGGCAGGTCAAGAAGGCCAAACAGACACTAAACGTAAATCGAAATCTTC\
          TTCAACCTACGATCACATTCAACTAGAGTCTGAGCGTACACAAGAAGAAACATCGAACACGCAGTCTCG\
          TTCAACAGGTACACGTCAAGGGAGATACTAA")

def best_matching_hit(seq):
    try:
        result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seq,  hitlist_size=1)
    except:
        print('BLAST run failed!')
        return None
    blast_record = result_handle.read()
   
    print(blast_record)


best_matching_hit(seq)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to compare the E-value (hsp.expect) with an undefined variable max_hsps, which isn't necessary for retrieving the best hit. also, to limit the number of hits, you should use the hitlist_size parameter in NCBIWWW.qblast instead of max_hsps. I've provided a corrected version of your function that properly retrieves and prints the information of the best hit, or indicates if no hits are found.

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from Bio.Seq import Seq

def best_matching_hit(seq):
    try:
        result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", seq, hitlist_size=1)
    except Exception as e:
        print('BLAST run failed:', e)
        return None
    
    blast_record = NCBIXML.read(result_handle)
    if blast_record.alignments:
        best_hit = blast_record.alignments[0] # Access the first (best) alignment
        best_hsp = best_hit.hsps[0] ## Access the first high-scoring segment pair
        print("Best Hit Title:", best_hit.title) 
        print("Best Hit Subject Sequence:", best_hsp.sbjct)
        #if u want alignment aswell u can do below one otherwise skip these four steps and continue with else
        print("Alignment:")
        print(best_hsp.query)
        print(best_hsp.match)
        print(best_hsp.sbjct)
    else:
        print("No hits found.")

seq = Seq("ATGGCGTGGAATGAGCCTGGAAATAACAACGGCAACAATGGCCGCGATAATGACCCTTGGGGTAATAA\
          TAATCGTGGTGGCCAGCGTCCTGGTGGCCGAGATCAAGGTCCGCCAGATTTAGATGAAGTGTTCAACAA\
          ACTGAGTCAAAAGCTGGGTGGCAAGTTTGGTAAAAAAGGCGGCGGTGGTTCCTCTATCGGCGGTGGCGG\
          TGGTGCAATTGGCTTTGGTGTCATTGCGATCATTGCAATTGCGGTGTGGATTTTCGCTGGTTTTTACAC\
          CATCGGTGAAGCAGAGCGTGGTGTTGTACTGCGTTTAGGTAAATACGATCGTATCGTAGACCCAGGCCT\
          TAACTGGCGTCCTCGTTTTATTGATGAATACGAAGCGGTTAACGTACAAGCGATTCGCTCACTACGTGC\
          ATCTGGTCTAATGCTGACGAAAGATGAAAACGTAGTAACGGTTGCAATGGACGTTCAATACCGAGTTGC\
          TGACCCATACAAATACCTATACCGCGTGACCAATGCAGATGATAGCTTGCGTCAAGCAACAGACTCTGC\
          GCTACGTGCGGTAATTGGTGATTCACTAATGGATAGCATTCTAACCAGTGGTCGTCAGCAAATTCGTCA\
          AAGCACTCAAGAAACACTAAACCAAATCATCGATAGCTATGATATGGGTCTGGTGATTGTTGACGTGAA\
          CTTCCAGTCTGCACGTCCGCCAGAGCAAGTAAAAGATGCGTTTGATGACGCGATTGCTGCGCGTGAGGA\
          TGAAGAGCGTTTCATCCGTGAAGCAGAAGCTTACAAGAACGAAATCTTGCCGAAGGCAACGGGTCGTGC\
          TGAACGTTTGAAGAAGGAAGCTCAAGGTTACAACGAGCGTGTAACTAACGAAGCATTAGGTCAAGTAGC\
          ACAGTTTGAAAAACTACTACCTGAATACCAAGCGGCTCCTGGCGTAACACGTGACCGTCTGTACATTGA\
          CGCGATGGAAGAGGTTTACACCAACACATCTAAAGTGTTGATTGACTCTGAATCAAGCGGCAACCTTTT\
          GTACCTACCAATCGATAAATTGGCAGGTCAAGAAGGCCAAACAGACACTAAACGTAAATCGAAATCTTC\
          TTCAACCTACGATCACATTCAACTAGAGTCTGAGCGTACACAAGAAGAAACATCGAACACGCAGTCTCG\
          TTCAACAGGTACACGTCAAGGGAGATACTAA")
best_matching_hit(seq)
```